# Piping input to an already running cpp program?

Tags: c++, pipe

## include

Lets assume that this is the code I am running:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

bool running = true;
string lineInput;
while (running)
{
    while (cin >> lineInput)
    {
        cout << lineInput;
    }
}

return 0;
```

}

What I would like to have happen is that I can call start a program from terminal by typing "./myProgram" That part is fairly straight forward. The part I'm not sure how to do is make it so that I can at a later point in time type `echo "some text to echo" | myProgram` and be able to have my program then print that text back out to the terminal.

Right now I can only make it work if I type:

`echo "blah blah blah" | ./myProgram`

So my goal is to have two separate steps. One where I start my program, and a second when I pipe it some input to use

Comment: you actually answered your own question; you require a pipe so use **mkfifo** and run it in background - link your program to it and later provide your input to pipe created using mkfifo

----> which is already answered by csreap3r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking you could do this with a named pipe.

```
mkfifo mypipe
./myProgram < mypipe &
cat file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt > mypipe
```

Comment: So this definitely works, but once myProgram gets to the end of the piped data, it stops reading. So it seems like it is a one time deal. Is there any way to make this work without needing to restart the program each time? It would be nice if I could cat 7 or 8 different files to the pipe in a row and have them all be worked on by the program

Comment: See updated answer, I believe an EOF is sent once the data is piped through, you can use the cat command with multiple files.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking too. Is it possible to ignore the EOF with the pipe somehow? Best case would be that I could put something through the pipe as I get the information. So I might get a bunch of data and send it through, and then an hour later receive more data and want to send that through as well. One solution could be that I remove the pipe and reconnect it again every time I want to send data, but this seems messier than it needs to be.

Comment: @CM0491: to avoid EOF: `tail -f mypipe | ./myProgram &`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mkfifo`, and just read from that in the program as from an ordinary file.

There's also

- `pipe` or `socket_pair` (bi-directional)

Comment: `pipe` and `socketpair` won't help here.